# Adding toleration to FluxCD bootstrap

Tags: fluxcd

I am trying to add some tolerations for the FluxCD pod, but could not understand the syntax for tolerations

here is how i was trying

```
flux bootstrap github \
  --toleration-keys='name=dedicated,value=Group' \
  --components-extra=image-reflector-controller,image-automation-controller \
  --owner=mak \
  --repository=mu \
  --path=yo \
  --branch=main \
  --version=v2.0.1 \
  --token-auth
```

here is my other helm chart toleration that work for reference

```
tolerations:
  - key: dedicated
    operator: "Equal"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
    value: Group
```

what tried added above
error

```
✗ Deployment/flux-system/helm-controller dry-run failed, reason: Invalid: Deployment.apps "helm-controller" is invalid: [spec.template.spec.tolerations[0].key: Invalid value: "name=dedicated": name part must consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'MyName',  or 'my.name',  or '123-abc', regex used for validation is '([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9]'), spec.template.spec.tolerations[1].key: Invalid value: "value=Group": name part must consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'MyName',  or 'my.name',  or '123-abc', regex used for validation is '([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9]')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show how you tried to add the toleration to the Flux controllers, but your reference seems correct to me.

Flux controllers can be customized during bootstrap using [Kustomize strategic merge patches and JSON patches](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/patchMultipleObjects.md).

First, create the file structure required by bootstrap, based on your command, it would look like this

```
BOOTSTRAP_PATH=mu/yo/flux-system
mkdir -p "$BOOTSTRAP_PATH"
touch "$BOOTSTRAP_PATH/gotk-components.yaml" \
  "BOOTSTRAP_PATH/gotk-sync.yaml" \
  "$BOOTSTRAP_PATH/kustomization.yaml" \
  "$BOOTSTRAP_PATH/toleration-patch.yaml"
```

Now, modify the patch file to add the toleration that will be added to Flux controllers.

```
// toleration-patch.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: flux
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      tolerations:
        - key: dedicated
          operator: Equal
          effect: NoSchedule
          value: Group
```

After creating the patch file, let's add it to the Kustomization file.

```
// kustomization.yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - gotk-sync.yaml
  - gotk-components.yaml
patches:
  - patch: toleration-patch.yaml
    target:
      kind: Deployment
      labelSelector: "app.kubernetes.io/part-of=flux"
```

This will apply the patch to all controllers, because we're targeting all Deployment objects that have the "app.kubernetes.io/part-of=flux" label.

Push the changes

```
git add -A && git commit -m "init flux" && git push
```

Run the bootstrap command.

```
flux bootstrap github \
  --toleration-keys='name=dedicated,value=Group' \
  --components-extra=image-reflector-controller,image-automation-controller \
  --owner=mak \
  --repository=mu \
  --path=yo \
  --branch=main \
  --version=v2.0.1 \
  --token-auth
```

That's it, before applying the components, the toleration will be add to the controllers.

Comment: Hey !
Its been a while since i asked this, 
But yes, i pretty much went the way u described,
Although i mentioned individual deployment one after another, but i do like ur approach better with single label that caters to all deployment in flux, Appreciate the feedback and would definitely give this a try 
Cheers mate